# Value of the exact same simulation

Tags: ethics

Imagine that you are able to run simulations of people, and decide to run twice the same simulation, who run in exactly the same way, and in this simulations something bad happens to the person being simulated, is it twice as bad because you run it twice, or could we consider that it only happened once because the two events are indistinguishable?

Similarly, what if I run twice the same simulation, and a different third one, if I had to stop one, wouldn't it be more ethical to stop one of the same simulations instead of the different one?

Comment: Simulations of people are not people, so what happens in them is ethically moot, unless it affects real people somehow.

Comment: @Conifold Does that mean if I can prove the universe is a simulation, it's okay to murder you?

Comment: The kind of "simulation" this universe can be can not be run the same way twice. The word is not used in the naive sense you are thinking of.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by 'simulation'. I think your question would gain moral relevance if you settled for cloning rather than simulation. Whatever  a simulation of myself might be, a clone is definitely a person and therefore morally considerable.

Comment: By simulation, I meant a computer program that is able to reproduce a person thoughts (assuming the monist point of view that there is nothing particular about our brain that cannot be simulated by a program). We could get rid of the randomness so that all simulations offer the same conditions, and all simulated brains experience the same things and think the same. In my opinion simulated people in this case should be thought as people.

Comment: The issue with a clone is that, as far as I understand, due to the randomness inherent to quantum mechanics, we would never be able to create exactly the same conditions for the clone and the original, and they will diverge at some point.
But I guess that if we imagine that we are able to offer exactly the same environment to a clone and his original, we can replace simulation by clone for the sake of the argument.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If people as we use the term to refer to ourselves are somehow simulations (and there is no scientific evidence this is the case), morality and ethics would be relatively unaffected.

Comment: To summarize, we need to imagine simulated people who are puppets in a mechanical puppet show replayed over and over by something else. Or maybe pixelated images. And then we *also* need to imagine that they are real people, and empathize. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Conifold. I am not aware of any scientific proof that would rule that out, or any proof that would say that we ourselves cannot be in such simulation, so no, I do not see the problem. But my question is not about the possibility of a conscious simulation (let's assume it is possible, even if it isn't) but about the value of distinct but identical simulations. Or let's imagine clones if that's easier, having all the same experiences and thoughts.

Comment: You are asking a question about ethics, scientific proofs have nothing to say about moral values. And you are asking us to attach moral value to something that by your design lacks it. Let's say a computer, or whatever runs the simulation, can attach "consciousness" (whatever that is) to its puppets, they will still be puppets. Our computers attach some data file to videogame characters as is, but it is the processor that animates it, not them. If anything, it is the simulator, if it was moving its puppets willfully, that could be empathized with for having to "kill" them over and over again.

Comment: Sorry I must not have been clear, I never said scientific proofs would say anything about morals. I said there was no scientific proof showing that we do not live in a simulation like the one I described. Could you explain why you think that a process that happens in the brain could not be reproduced by a program? Everyone can have an opinion on that of course, but as far as I know the debate is far from settled. But again, my question is not about the possibility or not of simulations...

Comment: Whether it could or could not is moot as far as your question is concerned. If it is true that our world is a deterministic simulation then me giving you permission to kill me or you taking me up on the offer (or not) matters not a wit. It is predetermined what either of us would do, and it is not even us doing it, really. Intuitive morality and value do not come without control over outcomes, and are conditioned on determinism being false. One can explain why we would still have them even if determinism is true (this is called compatibilism), but you are asking us to apply it intuitively.

Comment: But how is that relevant to the question, we are not judging the morality of the people living in the simulations, only the people controlling the simulations. Perhaps we live in a non deterministic simulation. But even if we discovered that we live in a deterministic world, I have trouble believing that morality will disappear overnight. IMO morality is a set of rules that societies choose, breaking them or not is morality, it doesn't matter if we have true free will, and yes, it is us doing it, because we are nothing more than the processes who made us, there would be no higher level "us".

Comment: We will not discover either way, determinism is neither verifiable nor falsifiable. But while it is cogent to entertain it in ontology it is pointless to do so in ethics, it makes it redundant. You are right, illusion of "morality" will not disappear, but we need actual morality to answer the question. If you want a compatibilist answer from a point of view of an agnostic observer that provisionally ascribes value to puppets based on their overt behavior then you shouldn't explicitly assume determinism, and specify a particular "set of rules" you want, because intuitive "rules" are unusable.